# Moondroid Coverflow Android Remove shadow effect

Tags: android, carousel

I am using Moondroid Coverflow Scroll in my project I followed the github code. I want to customize it and I am not finding how to remove the shadow effect.

Answer (score 6):

you can try this code in your project. it worked for me.

```
<it.moondroid.coverflow.components.ui.containers.FeatureCoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/coverflow"
    coverflow:coverHeight="150dp"
    coverflow:coverWidth="100dp"
    coverflow:maxScaleFactor="1.5"
    coverflow:rotationThreshold="0.5"
    coverflow:scalingThreshold="0.5"
    coverflow:spacing="0.6"
    coverflow:reflectionGap="0px"
    coverflow:reflectionOpacity="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to remove the shadow effect from this code :
`coverflow:reflectionOpacity = "0"`

```
<it.moondroid.coverflow.components.ui.containers.FeatureCoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/coverflow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:coverWidth="130dp"
    coverflow:reflectionOpacity="0"/>
```